# OpenAS2 Server SSL configuration, configuring and applying certificates on Windows

Tags: ssl

Using OpenAS2 server, I am able to transfer files from one machine to another machine without SSL. But I am stuck when I try to transfer files using SSL. Can somebody please help me with a step by step process to configure SSL, configuring and applying certificates in OpenAS2 Server.

Thanks in advance,
Sarath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export or download all site certificates you need to connect to.
2. Purchase or generate your own certificate with Private key. 
       https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html
3. Download http://keystore-explorer.org/
4. create a new Keystore (JKS Type)
5. Import all certificates from #1 & #2,  ensure that your site certificate shows padlock (indicating presence of private key). Make notes of the aliases used for each cert.
6. Save file created from #4 to the ./config folder of your OpenAS2 installation
7. Update your config.xml file to reference the file.  [[ org.openas2.processor.receiver.AS2ReceiverModule & AS2MDNReceiver  sections]]
8. update partnership.xml file with appropriate alias names as the  x509_alias  certificate name. (case sensitive)
9. re-start openas2
10. check log files for errors.